# Calling main inside of main in c

Tags: c, program-entry-point

I'd like to ask why when I have:

```
int main() {
    printf( "Hello world") ;
    main ;
}
```

the compiler prints "Hello world", 
but when I have main() instead of main, it prints repeatedly "Hello world".

Comment: @JoulinRouge That oh-so-smart comment doesn't explain the _difference_ between the two ways of using the identifier `main`, which seems to be the real question here.

Comment: Such as it may help with the thoroughly correct answers below: C allows a statement to be a mere expression — something that is evaluated but has no effect whatsoever on state. Modern compilers will usually issue a warning.

Comment: @underscore_d just posted for the "did you mean: recursion" thing. the difference has already been explained. Do you want me to remove it?

Comment: @JoulinRouge I confess I didn't even know Google had that joke, heh. I don't mind if you removed it or not; I was just clarifying that the question seemed to be about the difference, not 'why is this repeating'.

Answer (score 4):

```
int main() {
    printf( "Hello world") ;
    main ;
}
```

The last statement `main ;` has virtually no meaning: it just take the function designator, have it converted to a pointer pointing at the function, then throw the result away.

```
int main() {
    printf( "Hello world") ;
    main() ;
}
```

This code uses "main-recursion". The function `main()` is called inside `main()`. This recursive call will continue infinitely, and it may crash somewhere when the stack ran out or it may go until you stop by Ctrl+C or something if the compiler is smart enough to convert this tail recursion into a simple loop.

Comment: I'd add that a decent compiler should warn on the first case: _warning: statement with no effect_

Comment: @LPs: That would require enabling warnings. Something beginners tend to avoid, because they "get too much irritating messages" ... :-(( - Honestly, I got exactly that explanation from a student once!

Comment: @Olaf Hard to believe, right? I celebrate when my program generates no warnings. Or rather, when the only warning it generates is that one misdiagnosis due to some `g++` bug...

Comment: @underscore_d: I was literally speachless. And that really happens very rarely. Not to mention that student did not pass the course (for writing rubbish code and not knowing the language, not just for that attitude).

Answer (score 2):

`main();` will call the function recursively (and eventually crash due to a stack overflow, unless your compiler has cleverly optimised the recursion out to a loop).

`main` is an *expression* with a value equal to the *address* of the function `main()`. It's a no-op but nonetheless syntactically valid.

(Note that the behaviour of calling `main` from itself is *undefined* in C++, but is valid in C. Omitting the return value from `main` is also well-defined in C: 0 is assumed).

Comment: Omitting the return value of `main` leads to `0` being assumed in C++ too, since it adopts that (like various, but not _all_, other things) from C99. I hadn't realised they differed in positions on recursion within `main()`... not that I would ever want to use that anyway!

Answer (score 1):

This is because:

```
main()
```

is a method call. You are recursively calling the main function repeatedly. This will run until the call stack overflows.

```
main
```

Is a function pointer, so you're not really doing much on this line. The function exits after printing "Hello World" once.

Answer (score 0):

`main` is a function pointer whereas `main()` is function call.

When you write `main` it's just a *statement*, you are not using it or modifying it anywhere but main() is function call which will be a recursive (infinite in this case) call.